# embedding services in twig templates

Tags: symfony, twig

I am using controllers as services and try to embed those controllers in the twig template using the following syntax:

```
{% render 'my_controller:thisAction' %}
{% render 'my_controller2:this2Action' %}
{% render 'my_controller3:this3Action' %}
```

The problem is that instead of getting parsed correctly, only the first render statement is able to render the template and the following ones are not.

Any suggestions why this problem is occuring ?

Comment: what happens when you remove the first one? is the next one rendered then?

Comment: Also, check that you services are correctly enabled in the DI component. Run `php app/console container:debug` and check that all your service ids are there.

Comment: @Jaitsu yes, the problem was that 2nd time the template called was this2Action..twig which was not found , I solved it by explicitly giving it the templating service and then using $this->templating->renderResponse method

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure the naming convention is respected. And you do not need your controller to be services. Controllers are meant to grab a `Request` and return a `Response`.

Imagine you have a Controller called Default.

```
namespace Renoir\SiteBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{

    // ...

    public function randomNameRenderAction()
    {
       // Do some logic
    }

}
```

In the view you could call by using

```
{% render 'RenoirSiteBundle:Default:randomNameRender' %}
```

Comment: you are correct @renoirb but we are using controller as service . just to reduce the load of re-instantiating :)

Comment: Uhm. Even though.  Controller are meant for Request/Response, if you need to do logic, I recommend a Manager or a Handler. I still do not get your question exactly for it seems to me that your [controller logical names](http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_architecture.html#logical-controller-names) versus templates feels erroneous to me. Can you adjust and be more specific about your real issue please :)